# I have a trouble with initial setup form api-platform/client-generator for react native/ expo

Tags: react-native, expo, api-platform.com

I follow the guide [form api-platform](https://api-platform.com/docs/client-generator/react-native/) 
and get an error on initial expo run

```
$ yarn global add expo-cli
$ expo init my-app
# When asked, choose to use the blank template
$ cd my-app

$ yarn add redux react-redux redux-thunk redux-form react-native-elements react-native-router-flux react-native-vector-icons prop-types whatwg-url buffer react-native-event-source

$npx @api-platform/client-generator https://demo.api-platform.com . --generator react-native --resource book
```

after that you need to modify the App.js and create Route.js from this link  https://api-platform.com/docs/client-generator/react-native/#generating-a-native-app

and run

```
expo start
```

and I got an error

```
Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `ListComponent`.

This error is located at:
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at ScrollView.js:976)
    ...

This error is located at:
    in NavigationContainer (at Router.js:97)
    in App (at Router.js:122)
    in Router (at Router.js:8)
    in RouterComponent (at App.js:34)
  ...
```

[issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D686O.jpg)

Comment: Did you validate imports for elements in Listcomponent

Comment: oh yes I checked and the problem was in outdated import of react-native-elements List component spasibo )

Answer (score 0):

api-platform/client-generator using old version of react-native-elements

type in console

```
 expo install react-native-elements@0.19.1
```

and it works